# DataTrigger to attached property present in Parent Control i.e. Child's PlacementTarget property

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I want to apply a DataTrigger on the attached property present in Parent Control.

Here I am applying DataTigger in ToolTip style and attached property is present in ToolTip Parent i.e. its PlacementTarget.

I am trying like this

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:ViewCommands.AlwaysShowToolTip), Source=PlacementTarget}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility"Value="Visible" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But still child control is hidden. How to do that?

Comment: I thought Path is a StringLiteral point to a property on your source object, which could be the key to your local:ViewCommands resource, i'm not sure yet what the PlacementTarget would be, can you give more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are declaring the `DataTrigger` in the ToolTip's Style, you should use Self `RelativeSource`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.(local:ViewCommands.AlwaysShowToolTip), RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility"Value="Visible" />
</DataTrigger>
```